# Git Bash not executing install command

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium and having trouble getting the following line to execute using GitBash:

`$ ./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install`

Return value:

```
Usage: selenium-standalone action [options]
```

However, there is a directory that contains that file: `C:\Users\chris.shaw\Desktop\WebdriverIO_Framework\node_modules\.bin\selenium-standalone`

Here is my complete Git Bash syntax/command:

`chris.shaw@9HKZ1N2 MINGW64 ~/desktop/WebdriverIO_Framework
$ ./node_modules/.bin/selenium-standalone install`

I do not see anything incorrect - also, I am in an Udemy class for selenium and it works fine on the class video when the instructor does the same. I also have reached out to the instructor for help. But wanted to throw out a line here too.